# Rails Webpacker 3.0 import CSS file is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I am working Rails5 project with Webpacker in order to run React properly

But when `import` my css file inside my root component seems it is not working at all. Looking like stylesheet is not coming at all.

This is my root Component

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import StartForm from './insurance_form/start_form'
//import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
// not working

ReactDOM.render(
  <StartForm />,
  document.getElementById('start-form-index-container')
)
```

This my `webpack/environment.js`

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const myCssLoaderOptions = {
    modules: true,
    sourceMap: true,
    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
}

const CSSLoader = environment.loaders.get('style').use.find(el => el.loader === 'css-loader')

CSSLoader.options = merge(CSSLoader.options, myCssLoaderOptions)

module.exports = environment
```

So how i can make imported css working well with webpacker?

Thanks!

Comment: I met same problem. Have you solved this yet ?

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem just now and found a solution.  Hopefully this helps someone else.

I'm using webpacker 3.4.3.  It uses the [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to auto-generate a CSS pack containing the imported styles.  It takes the same name as your JS pack.  So if your JS pack is `hello_react.jsx`, and in it you import some CSS like so: `import "./Hello.css";`, the styles in `Hello.css` are included in a CSS pack called `hello_react.css`.  In your Rails view you can add something like `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag('hello_react.css') %>`, and the styles should work.

For more info, see the [Link styles from your Rails view](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/css.md) section of the Webpacker CSS docs.

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting this to work with `less` files after compilation. Do you happen to know if there are any caveats for precompiled stylesheets?