# Sass support in Rails 5.2 with webpacker 3+ directly in JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, webpacker

I want to include SASS support in a brand new Rails App directly importing the .scss file on my Javascript files.

So far this is what I have done:

1- Follow `https://github.com/rails/webpacker` to create a new webpacker rails app with react integrations. Hello world was succesfull.

I have a entry point for Webpacker in `packs` folder

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Hello from "../hello_world";

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      ReactDOM.render(
        <Hello name="React" />,
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
      );
    });
```

3 - My Hello world component

```
import React from "react";
import "./test.scss";

const Hello = props => <div className="red">Hello {props.name}!</div>;

export default Hello;
```

4 - My sass file

```
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

5 - view

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_world_pack' %>
```

6 - layout template

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Myapp</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

No complaints at all but `Red` color is not applied. What I overlook?

**NOTE:** Successfully I could add SASS support but adding a `my_stylehseet.scss` file directly in `pack` folder and referencing it into my layout template with `<% = stylesheet_pack_tag 'my_stylesheet %>'. But I want that my template is stylesheet agnostic s I don't have to have severals of them.

I really think there is an more elegant way If I understood properly webpacker doc `https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/css.md` 
Maybe Am I wrong?

Comment: I found out that the question was already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257346/rails-webpacker-3-0-import-css-file-is-not-working actually the webPacker documentation was pointing the solution and I was quite close. we need include a CSS file into pack folder

Answer (score 1):

Just for the records the question is already answered here [Rails Webpacker 3.0 import CSS file is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257346/rails-webpacker-3-0-import-css-file-is-not-working) and the webpacker documentation is clear about it https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/css.md